# How do I create a String array with its elements being all the png files located in a resource folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, jbutton, executable-jar

I am trying to create a method that searches inside a folder for .png files and returns a String array with the respective path to each file. It must look inside a resource folder **placed NOT in the src, but in project.**
The following code works when running from within Eclipse:

```
// Analyzes specified folder and returns a file array
// populated with the .png files found in that folder
private File[] imageReader(String filePath) {
    File folder = new File(filePath);
    return folder.listFiles (new FilenameFilter() { 
        public boolean accept(File filePath, String filename)
        { return filename.endsWith(".png"); }
    });
}

// Converts the file array into a string array
private String[] listPngFiles(String filePath) {
    File[] imagesFileArray = imageReader(filePath); // file array
    String[] imagesStringArray = new String[imagesFileArray.length];

    for(int i=0; i<imagesFileArray.length; i++) {
        imagesStringArray[i] = "" + imagesFileArray[i];
        imagesStringArray[i] = imagesStringArray[i].substring(6);   // discards "/images" from directory string
    }

    return imagesStringArray;
}
```

However it is not working when I run the exported executable JAR file. This is my current project setup:

[image: project setup].

I have tried the following code but it did not work either:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File folder = new File(classLoader.getResource(filePath).getFile());
```

The reason I am doing this is because I want to have a JButton display an icon chosen from one of the sub folders inside the images resource folder. My JButton already has the following code:

```
.setIcon(new ImageIcon(GameLogic.class.getResource(**insert listPngFiles array element here**)));
```

Your help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be simpler to put the names of all the images in some ini file in the resource folder, then open and read that file when you start the application? Resources don't change often, so there is no reason to do this in a dynamic read.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections), take a look at [getResources](https://reflections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/reflections/javadoc/apidocs/org/reflections/Reflections.html#getResources(java.util.regex.Pattern))